# Site renders differently in CFM vs HTML on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion, google-chrome

Ok, so this is very odd.  I have a site that I am breaking out into several ColdFusion documents for header/footer/etc.  The footer of my site is affixed to the bottom using a jQuery plugin.  When I go to the index.cfm page (in Chrome) to view the results, the footer placement is off.  I then "right-click...view source" and highlight all, then copy and paste it into  a new index2.html document, everything works fine.

That's right, exact same code, different results.  I don't get it.  This is not yet a live site so if you would like to see the 2 files in action, I can get you the URLs via email.  Just shoot me a request to ..nevermind.., and I will send you the URLs to the 2 pages.

All other browsers work fine, so Firebug is out of the question :(

This is seriously [mind bottling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWkNPrXkvRA).

Comment: Is the code/site available for public viewing?

Comment: its open to the public but id rather not put the url on the site, if youd like the url then please email me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White space may be playing into this.

Comment: how do you figure?, plus when i copied the view-source code from the cfm page, i took the whitespace with it

Comment: Check there is no whitespace before the DOCTYPE declaration.

If there is anything (including just a space or blank line) before the DOCTYPE, it might be throwing the browser into quirks mode.

Comment: there is whitespace prior to the doctype, however, it is present in both the cfm and the html document

Comment: you were absolutely right, i turned on whitespace management and removoved all whitespace from above the doctype and everything is perfect...thank you

Comment: I'm still curious as to the real cause as this doesn't explain the different rendering between the .cfm and .html extensions. Why would Chrome treat one extension differently to another? The only rationale I can come up with is the mimetypes on the server, but that's a little beyond my paygrade.

Comment: I believe that ColdFusion was outputting special characters that sent the browser into quirks mode.  When I copied the outputted markup, Windows must have converted those special characters to normal whitespace.